# Excel Macro Adjustment - Want to insert a picture at a specific point

Tags: vba, excel

This code inserts a picture into my excel worksheet, from a specific folder, by entering the name of the picture into a cell. For example, if I was to enter a1.jpg into cell J4, I would then get an output of the image that I want from the folder to a cell that is one space to the right of J4.

The dilemma I'm having is that my excel template has various sized cells and I am trying to place the picture in a specific location but having a hard time. This is because the current code moves the picture by cells so if the cell is too long, the picture will be moved the whole length of the cell. I was wondering if this could be changed such that the image can be placed directly at a certain point and not designated by cells.

code credit goes to pokemon_Man

The code is as follows:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim imagePath, fileName, fullImagePath, newImageLoc As String

        imagePath = "C:\YourFileLocationPath\"
        If Target.Address = "$J$4" Then 
            fullImagePath = imagePath & Target.Value
            newImageLoc = Target.Offset(, 1).Address 

            With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fullImagePath)
                .Left = ActiveSheet.Range(newImageLoc).Left
                .Top = ActiveSheet.Range(newImageLoc).Top
                .Placement = 1
                .PrintObject = True
            End With
            End
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You can use fixed values instead of (e.g.) `ActiveSheet.Range(newImageLoc).Left`, or adjust the position by adding/substracting amounts from those coordinates.

Comment: Thanks that works! How about if I wanted to move the image from the middle instead of the top left?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 .Left = Target.Left + Target.Width / 2
 .Top = Target.Top + Target.Height / 2
```